# getting error while trying to upload image to node server

Tags: javascript, node.js

Using this tutorial I want to upload images to my database, So I have this in server side:

```
router.post('/upload', upload.single('upload'), async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const incident = await Incident.findById(req.body.id)
        incident.image = req.file.buffer
        incident.save()
        res.send()
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(400).send(e)
    }
}, (error, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(400).send({
        error: error.message
    })
})
```

And I have the binary data of the image like this in front end:

> data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/4gIoSUNDX1BST0ZJTEUAAQEAAAIYAAAAAAIQAABtbnRyUkdCIFhZWiAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABhY3NwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAA9tYAAQAAAADTLQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

In the tutorial it shows us that we can send a image via postman like this:

[image]

I used this to do the same thing as tutorial did in postman using fetch api with no luck:

```
const data = new FormData();
data.append("upload", image); // the image is the binary data I showed you

fetch('/accounts/upload', {
        // headers: {
        //     'Accept': 'application/json',
        //     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        // },
        method: 'post',
        body: data,
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => console.log(result))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

But I get `400 (Bad Request)` each time!!

How can I fix this?

I figured out that `req.body` is empty object like : {} So I think there is something wrong with fetch maybe

EDIT 2: Here is a log from data inside:

```
function uploadImage(image) {
      const data = new FormData();
      data.append("upload", image);
      console.log(data); // added this to log the data
      fetch('/accounts/upload-image', {
          method: 'post',
          body: data,
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result => console.log(result))
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }
```

Result o the log is:

[image]

Comment: It appears you are trying to access the route `/accounts/upload`, while the server route is `/upload`.

Comment: Or maybe /incidents/upload going by PostMan

Comment: I hit the route correctly guys that's not the issue...

Comment: Please have a look at edit 2....

Comment: Are you getting any message from the server in the response body of the 400?  You should either get the result of "e" or "error: error.message" showing up.

Comment: The fromData is empty please have a look at Edit 2... I think this is not normal...